# Custom Domain already taken error in Github

Tags: github-pages, custom-domain

I am trying to add my custom domain for github pages but it is continuously giving error that `the Domain is already taken`. I have already verified my custom domain on github with TXT DNS entry. But as soon as I add github IPs in A DNS entry, it starts pointing to some other project that is not mine. I also tried adding CNAME entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. As pointed out by GitHub Support:

> This error generally occurs when a custom domain has previously been owned by another GitHub user, or the domain has been added to a GitHub repository in error.

> After domain verification, it takes almost 7 days to remove it from its current repository.

If you want to get it released before that, you can contact
[GitHub Support](https://support.github.com/request/pages)